# replace with a string that depends on what found

Tags: html

If I want to replace

```
<a href="#some_garbage_text">1. First title</a>
```

with

```
<a href="#1">1. First title</a>
```

which means I want to replace the garbage text with the numbering in the content, how can I do that with command find and replace engine like the ones in VScode or sublime text?

I have tried:

- find: `#.*">[0-9]+\.`
- replace: `#$$0">$$0.`

This doesn't work at all and further, when the list goes long, numberings may have more digits, like "17. Some title". Better use only plain find and replace engines rather than other programmes or JS.

Comment: This can be done with very plain JavaScript or jQuery.

Comment: Bit of excel and sublime wold also  do this in min or two... Be resourceful...

Comment: What's the update on this? Found what you were looking for?

Answer (score 2):

You could do it in jQuery:

```js
$('a').each((i, a) => {
  $(a).attr('href', '#' + parseInt($(a).text()));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#first_garbage_text">1. First title</a>
<a href="#second_garbage_text">2. Second title</a>
<a href="#third_garbage_text">3. Third title</a>
```

or in pure JavaScript:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(a => {
  a.href = '#' + parseInt(a.innerHTML);
});
```

```html
<a href="#first_garbage_text">1. First title</a>
<a href="#second_garbage_text">2. Second title</a>
<a href="#third_garbage_text">3. Third title</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with Vanilla Javascript using a regex matching the first digit of the string :

```
^[\d]*
```

You can test it here : https://regex101.com/r/Vq0Vm0/1

Something like that will work :

```js
const $aList = document.querySelectorAll('a');
const pattern = /^[\d]*/g;

$aList.forEach($a => {
  const digit = $a.textContent.match(pattern)[0];
  $a.setAttribute('href', `#${digit}`);
});
```

```html
<a href="#some_garbage_text">1. First title</a>
<a href="#some_garbage_text">17. First title</a>
<a href="#some_garbage_text">1456456. First title</a>
<a href="#some_garbage_text">1456546654. First title</a>
<a href="#some_garbage_text">1546456. First title</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would personally use jQuery alongside a `RegEx` match to extract the number in the string.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-4 d-flex justify-content-center">
        <button class="btn-primary btn-change-content">Change content</button>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-md-4 d-flex justify-content-center">
        <a href="#some_garbage_text">1. First title.</a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-md-4 d-flex justify-content-center">
        <a href="#some_garbage_text">2. Second title.</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.btn-change-content').on("click", function() {
    $('a').each(function () {
        var anchorText = $(this).text();
        var num = anchorText.match(/\d+/)[0];
        $(this).attr("href", "#"+num);
    });
});

$('a').on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var hrefAttr = $(this).attr("href");
    
    alert(hrefAttr);
});
```

**Snippet: (try to first click the anchor tags, then change content and click them again)**

```js
$('.btn-change-content').on("click", function() {
    $('a').each(function () {
        var anchorText = $(this).text();
        var num = anchorText.match(/\d+/)[0];
        $(this).attr("href", "#"+num);
    });
});

$('a').on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var hrefAttr = $(this).attr("href");
    
    alert(hrefAttr);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-4 d-flex justify-content-center">
        <button class="btn-primary btn-change-content">Change content</button>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-4 d-flex justify-content-center">
        <a href="#some_garbage_text">1. First title.</a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-4 d-flex justify-content-center">
        <a href="#some_garbage_text">2. Second title.</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Codepen Example [here](https://codepen.io/mbacode/pen/GRomQgN).